# Why is it called flash for phones / tablets and install for PCs

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, tablet, phone, flashing

Lets say that you want to change your device's operating system.For a phone or tablet we would say "today I am flashing cyanogenmod" but for PCs "today I am installing Ubuntu" although flash is used BIOS like "I am flashing an updated BIOS to my laptop". Why is it called flash,it is basically the same thing,replacing the operating system.Is this because phones and tablets use SSD / flash memory.But new computers also have SSDs

Comment: To a certain extent, it's just use of jargon to show off "technical" knowledge of the speaker/writer.  In professional publications, you would see less use of such jargon, and see functional verbs like "install".   Similarly you could use "transfer" instead of "download" and "upload".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not about harddisk or SSDs. On PCs we also call it flashing the **firmware**.

The firmware is what gets run when the device powers up. Usually from ROM, EEPROM or possibly from flash memory.

The OS onthe other hand is typically a higher layer and you do not flash it. You install it. Regardless if you use rotating rust or flash cells to write it to.

Comment: On a phone or tablet we are also just changing the OS.Not the fast boot or something

Comment: A phone is often optimised and has limited storage. All data is in the same storage backend (assuming no extra SD cards). On a PC it is typically a small non-eraseable part for the minimal startup, then over to HDD or PXE.  Same for routers, setup boxes etc. Small storage for the firmware. And also called flashing. And if you fail to succesfully flash you can brick a device. unlike with writing to a HDD/SSD.

Comment: You cannot brick a phone or tablet by flashing a bad ROM if it has an unlocked bootloader because fastboot will always be there

Comment: @SuiciDoga: Um, there are many other kinds of flashable devices, not just Android phones or tablets... Consider regular desktop computers, for example: in the earlier days, if a BIOS update went wrong, you had to actually remove the flash chip and flash it using an EEPROM writer, because BIOS itself *is* the "fastboot", there's nothing before it.

Answer (score 1):

First a short explanation about flsh storage:
It's called like that, because data stored on it cannot simply be 'updated' instead it would have to be deleted and completely rewritten (c.f. [block erasure of flash memory on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_memory#Block_erasure)).
The deletion happens by putting a current on all cells, reminding of a camera flash. Thus, the term flashing and flash memory was created.

In smartphones, one can see a similar behaviour: flashing overwrites the whole stored information, instead of changing small fractions of it.

In conclusion, flashing means complete replacement of existing data, installing means adding some information to / modifying it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the term 'flashing' was earlier used for writing [((E)E)PROM chips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM) on which devices store their firmware; depending on the device, there might be an online upgrade function, or one might need to use an actual EEPROM programmer device. (That's also where the term "ROM" comes from, since the chip *was* effectively read-only after programming it once.)

The main difference from installing is that you have a prepared image, and the firmware upgrade erases and rewrites the whole thing at once. Traditional OS installation, meanwhile, involves a lot of moving parts – copying individual files to an existing filesystem, setting up the configuration on the spot, etc.

Comment: Phones use flash memory not EEPROM

Comment: @SuiciDoga: Never said I was talking about phones.

Comment: Older devices used ROMs. Including phones. These days that is changed by the termology has stuck.

Comment: I've used PROMs and EEPROMs before Flash memory was introduced, and the term "flash" was never used.  The verbs used were "program" or "blow" (the fuses).  Someone else (in another post) claimed they used "burn" (even before writable optical discs were available).  You also have the origin of "ROM" wrong.  ROM was available before there was ever PROM.  You seem to be making this stuff up.

Answer (score 0):

"Flashing" a medium, refers to the programming or writing to a medium, typically in embedded systems, such as a single-board computer, or a phone. When you flash a phone, you are overwriting the operating system and (usually) most of the firmware (in driver form). This is usually a very specific platform that can only read an OS in one specific form (such as an Android OS by the Android bootloader, which runs the software, and lists the hardware.

The reason it is called flashing / imaging, is because you are copying a "pre-installed" system image to it. The system partition for every one of the same phone will be practically the same.

"Installing", on the other hand, normally refers to adding or configuring software to a computer or device. When you install an OS, you are preparing to run the OS.

In both cases, you are partitioning the storage, but when installing an OS, you are configuring it at run-time. The installer partitions the disk, then copies the OS files, and may set up user(s) or add drivers or additional software. In a lot of Linux installers, you are downloading the files fresh, as if you were updating an existing system, instead of a pre-configured system.

Comment: Was this wriiten by ChatGPT?